# Initialize Collection of DataTemplates in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, observablecollection

I have this `DependencyProperty`

```
public ObservableCollection<DataTemplate> WizardTemplateCollection
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<DataTemplate>)GetValue(WizardTemplateCollectionProperty); }
    set { SetValue(WizardTemplateCollectionProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty WizardTemplateCollectionProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("WizardTemplateCollection", typeof(ObservableCollection<DataTemplate>), typeof(CustomWizardControl), new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<DataTemplate>()));
```

And want to do this:

```
<custom:CustomWizardControl>
    <custom:CustomWizardControl.WizardTemplateCollection>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle></Rectangle>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle></Rectangle>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle></Rectangle>
        </DataTemplate>
    </custom:CustomWizardControl.WizardTemplateCollection>
</custom:CustomWizardControl>
```

What DataType do i need? Or how can i initialize a `ObservableCollection` in `XAML`.

Additional:

```
public class CustomWizardControl : Control {}
```

Comment: register DP with correct name: `DependencyProperty.Register("WizardTemplateCollection", ...`

Comment: Apart from wrong name why wouldn't you simply specify datatemplates in `<CustomWizardControl.Resources>` ? What is the purpose of such property?

Comment: Thanks but this still throws an exception. I corrected it.

Comment: What exception ? [Add](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43068894/edit) it to the question please.

Comment: That `DataTemplate` is no `DependencyObject`

Comment: XMLParse Exception is parent of this inner exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CustomWizardControl` class must inherit from `DepenedencyObject` or one of its derived types like for example `UIElement` or `Control`:

```
public class CustomWizardControl : Control
{
    public ObservableCollection<DataTemplate> WizardTemplateCollection
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<DataTemplate>)GetValue(WizardTemplateCollectionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(WizardTemplateCollectionProperty, value); }
    }
    ...
}
```

This works:

```
public class CustomWizardControl : Control
{
    public CustomWizardControl()
    {
        WizardTemplateCollection = new ObservableCollection<DataTemplate>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<DataTemplate> WizardTemplateCollection
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<DataTemplate>)GetValue(WizardTemplateCollectionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(WizardTemplateCollectionProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty WizardTemplateCollectionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("WizardTemplateCollection", typeof(ObservableCollection<DataTemplate>), typeof(CustomWizardControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

---

```
<local:CustomWizardControl x:Name="ctrl">
    <local:CustomWizardControl.WizardTemplateCollection>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle></Rectangle>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle></Rectangle>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle></Rectangle>
        </DataTemplate>
    </local:CustomWizardControl.WizardTemplateCollection>
</local:CustomWizardControl>
```

---

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding WizardTemplateCollection.Count, ElementName=ctrl}" />
```

Comment: It is a `Control` mate

Comment: I tried it with a `Control`, because I want to use this `class` - extended Template stuff. I did not work, but i had no time to try it a bit more.

Comment: What did not work? As I mentioned in my answe the class *must* inherit from a DependencyObject. Otherwise you cannot use depenendency properties in the first place. Also, my sample code clearly works.

Comment: Yes - my exception is about `DataTemplate` is no `DependencyObject` - what is true.

Comment: The DataTemplate objects that you add to the ObservableCollection don't need to be DependencyObjects. They are not. See my sample code again. It is the class where the WizardTemplateCollection property is defined that must be a DependencyObject.

Comment: I really thank :) you for your help i will check everything tomorrow - i have to do the build server first. You will get your checkmark or another comment tomorrow mate!

Comment: This is working - but as I said i need it with `Control` in a `Template`.

Comment: "Control in a Template"? Please clarify what you mean. Read this and updated your question accordingly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I am using a Custom Control with a Generic Template and i want the feature of the Control. So there is no use in showing that it works with UIElement.

Comment: It works with Control as the base class as well. Just change the base class type and try the very same example. I even edited my answer to clarify this.

Comment: Maybe I have another bad issue - but you answered my Question ! thank you mate

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the generic parameter of `ObservableCollection<T>` directly in XAML.

Instead you should create your custom `DataTemplateCollection` inherited from `ObservableCollection<DataTemplate>`. Then you will be able to use your collection as usual.

```
public class DataTemplateCollection : ObservableCollection<DataTemplate>
{
}

<custom:CustomWizardControl>
    <custom:CustomWizardControl.WizardTemplateCollection>
        <custom:DataTemplateCollection>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Rectangle></Rectangle>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Rectangle></Rectangle>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Rectangle></Rectangle>
            </DataTemplate>
        </custom:DataTemplateCollection>
    </custom:CustomWizardControl.WizardTemplateCollection>
</custom:CustomWizardControl>
```

Additional note: **NEVER** initialize the default value of dependency properties with mutable objects, because this single mutable instance will be used by every control instance. Instead you must set the default value to null and assing the initial value in the constructor.

Comment: But this still gives me that `DataTemplate` has to be derived from a `DependencyObject`

Comment: Hmm, that's very strange. Did you implement it like in my code snippet above: with the explicit DataTemplateCollection tag inside the custom:CustomWizardControl.WizardTemplateCollection tag?

Comment: Yes and a `DataTemplate` isnt a `DependencyObject`.