# ObservableCollection within control not being bound

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a chart control that has a `Series` property of `SeriesCollection` which inherits `ObservableCollection<Series>`. `Series` has a `Values` property of `ChartValues` which inherits `ObservableCollection<double>`. When I add `Series` to the `SeriesCollection` in `Xaml` the `Values` binding does not work for some reason and the `OnValuesChanged()` is never called.

If, however, I move the `Series` outside the `SeriesCollection`, the `OnValuesChanged()` is called.

**Chart.cs**

```
public class Chart : Control
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SeriesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Series), typeof(SeriesCollection), typeof(Chart),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(SeriesCollection),
                (s, e) => (s as Chart)?.OnSeriesChanged()));

    private Canvas _canvas;

    public Chart()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(Chart);
    }

    public SeriesCollection Series
    {
        get => (SeriesCollection) GetValue(SeriesProperty);
        set => SetValue(SeriesProperty, value);
    }

    public List<ChartGroup> Groups { get; private set; }

    private void SortChartGroups()
    {
        Groups = new List<ChartGroup>();

        var max = Series.Select(s => s.Values?.Count).Max();

        if (max > 0)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < max; i++)
            {
                var points = Series.SelectMany(s => s.ChartPoints).Where(c => c.Index == i).ToList();
                Groups.Add(new ChartGroup
                {
                    Index = i,
                    Values = points
                });
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnCollectionChanged()
    {
        Update();

    }

    private void OnSeriesChanged()
    {
        Series.CollectionChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            OnCollectionChanged();
        };

        OnCollectionChanged();
    }

    protected virtual void Update()
    {
        if (Series.Count > 0)
        {
            SortChartGroups();

            if (Groups.Count > 0)
            {
                var count = Series.Count;

                var values = Groups.SelectMany(g => g.Values.Select(p => p.Value)).ToList();

                var min = values.Min();
                var max = values.Max();

                // Draw here
                // Calculate drawing region

                Draw();
            }
        }
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        _canvas = GetTemplateChild("PART_Canvas") as Canvas;

        Loaded += (s, e) => Draw();
        SizeChanged += (s, e) => Draw();
    }

    private void Draw()
    {
        if (!IsLoaded || Series == null) return;

        //_canvas.Children.Clear();
    }
}
```

**SeriesCollection.cs**

```
public class SeriesCollection : ObservableCollection<Series>
{
}
```

**Series.cs**

```
public class Series : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValuesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Values), typeof(ChartValues), typeof(Series),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(ChartValues), 
                (s, e) => (s as Series)?.OnValuesChanged()));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(Title), typeof(string), typeof(Series), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(Color), typeof(Color), typeof(Series), new PropertyMetadata(default(Color)));

    internal Chart Chart { private get; set; }

    public string Title
    {
        get => (string) GetValue(TitleProperty);
        set => SetValue(TitleProperty, value);
    }

    public Color Color
    {
        get => (Color) GetValue(ColorProperty);
        set => SetValue(ColorProperty, value);
    }

    public ChartValues Values
    {
        get => (ChartValues) GetValue(ValuesProperty);
        set => SetValue(ValuesProperty, value);
    }

    internal List<ChartPoint> ChartPoints { get; private set; }

    private void OnCollectionChanged()
    {
        ChartPoints = new List<ChartPoint>();

        for (var i = 0; i < Values.Count; i++)
        {
            ChartPoints.Add(new ChartPoint
            {
                Title = Title,
                Value = Values[i],
                Index = i
            });
        }

        Chart?.OnCollectionChanged();
    }

    private void OnValuesChanged()
    {
        if (Values != null)
        {
            Values.CollectionChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                OnCollectionChanged();
            };

            OnCollectionChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

**ChartValues.cs**

```
public class ChartValues : ObservableCollection<double>
{
}
```

**Xaml**

The binding on the values property works if I move the `Series` outside the `SeriesCollection`, where `OnValuesChanged()` is called

```
<charts:Series Values="{Binding SomeValues}"/>
<charts:Series Values="{Binding OtherValues}" />
```

However, the bindings on the values doesn't work when placed inside the `SeriesCollection`, the class is initialised but the values property is never set by the binding and the `OnValuesChanged()` never called. The `Chart` `OnSeriesChanged()` is called and the `Series` property has 2 items in, but the binding on the `Values` never works.

```
<charts:Chart>
    <charts:Chart.Series>
        <charts:SeriesCollection>
            <charts:Series Values="{Binding SomeValues}"/>
            <charts:Series Values="{Binding OtherValues}" />
        </charts:SeriesCollection>
    </charts:Chart.Series>
</charts:Chart>
```

The reason I'm binding to the values is that I have other properties on the `Series` class which I'm setting in `xaml` that i don't really want to include in the view model, such as Title and Color

I've looked at answers from this post [Initialize Collection of DataTemplates in XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43068894/initialize-collection-of-datatemplates-in-xaml) but it doesn't seem to fix the issue I'm having.

**Edit**
I've tried binding to the `DataContext` of the user control and it can't find the `UserControl`. It seems that it isn't part of the visual tree?

```
<charts:Series Values="{Binding Path=DataContext.SomeValues, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>
```

**Edit**

**Chart.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:charts="<omitted>.Charts">

<Style TargetType="{x:Type charts:Chart}">

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type charts:Chart}">
                <Grid>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding Series}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type charts:Series}">

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type charts:Series}">
                <Grid>
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding Values}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

</Style>
```

**Generic.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <ResourceDictionary Source="/<omitted>;component/Themes/Chart.xaml" />

</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

**App.xaml**

```
<Application x:Class="<omitted>"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="<omitted>">
<Application.Resources>

    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Generic.xaml"/>

        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>

</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: `Chart` and `Series` are Custom Controls (inherit from `Control`). In that case, did you create corresponding `Generic.xaml`? And also, why then are you throwing a `UserControl` in the mix?

Comment: I have created the corresponding Generic.xaml for the controls. The user control (View) contains numerous charts with binding to the values from the ViewModel. I have created this chart as a control for usability and customisation, but i cant get binding to the values to work.

Comment: Please post your Generic.xaml.

Comment: Edited to include `Chart.xaml`, `Generic.xaml` and `App.xaml` as it currently is with omitted namepsaces.

Comment: For testing purposes, in the control template for your `Chart`, if you use, for instance, an `ItemsControl` rather than a `Canvas` you should see your list boxes.

Comment: The binding works by using the itemscontrol, which is odd, i don't understand why. Eventually the series are going to be drawn onto the Canvas, not through an items control though. thanks

Comment: Well, you have a collection of series, therefore you need a control able to show a list of series, like an `ItemsControl`.

Comment: BTW, if you properly define your dependency properties and because you're already using `ObservableCollection` you don't need to be concerned at all about binding and collection change events, it is all taken care for you.

Comment: I've updated the `Chart.cs` and `Series.cs` to include the other properties i have currently, i had previously omitted them because i didn't think they were relevant. What I'm trying to achieve is, when the `Values` in series have changed the chart should redraw on the the values on `canvas`. The series values are not going to be display, but the grouped values that are calculated from them are. Hope this makes sense?

Comment: Yes, but in that case wherever you store the result of that calculation in your view model, that variable must either implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` or be a `DependencyProperty`, otherwise your view will not be notified.

Comment: Setting the `Series` `DataContext` in the `OnSeriesChanged()` triggered by `SeriesCollection` callback fixed the issue

Comment: Not exactly sure what you fixed but I can tell you this: get a conceptual grip on how the MVVM pattern is supposed to work. It sounds to me you're taking random actions in order to fix whatever is wrong with your code. Unless you need to execute some custom **business logic** when your collection changes (other than updating the UI) then most likely there's no need for what you're doing. Finally, unless you're doing this for fun / educational purposes, there's good charting packages out there ready for you to use.

Comment: I am doing this for educational purposes yes and i believe i have a basic understanding of MVVM. I have a view with a chart. This view has a viewmodel which interacts with business services to get data to be bound to the charts, ie values, titles, axis labels. These bindings are used in the chart control and the chart control will display and draw these values to a canvas, ie Akima cubic spline. This is the educational part. Thanks